# I have a blinking box, how can I add a gradient to this or program it easier?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was trying to figure out how to get a blinking box, and as I did not really find a solution on the net, I was fiddling around a bit.

I came up with the following, this works fine in general. My question is simply a) if there is an easier way to do this, and b) if I can program it in a way that it increases / decreases by gradient, instead of me having to program so many classes and stuff like that.

See this code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUJ5b/7/

html

```
<div id="test" class="test">Hello</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(blink, 75);
});

function blink() {
    if ($('#test').hasClass("test")) {
        $("#test").removeClass('test').addClass('test1');
    } else if($('#test').hasClass("test1")) {
        $("#test").removeClass('test1').addClass('test2');
    } else if($('#test').hasClass("test2")) {
        $("#test").removeClass('test2').addClass('test3');
    } else if($('#test').hasClass("test3")) {
        $("#test").removeClass('test3').addClass('test5');
    } else if($('#test').hasClass("test4")) {
        $("#test").removeClass('test4').addClass('test5');
    } else if($('#test').hasClass("test5")) {
        $("#test").removeClass('test5').addClass('test6');
    } else if($('#test').hasClass("test6")) {
        $("#test").removeClass('test6').addClass('test7');
    } else {
        $("#test").removeClass('test7').addClass('test');
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.test {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px #ED0 outset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px #FE4;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px #FE4;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px #FE4;
}
.test1 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px #EED000 outset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px #FFE544;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px #FFE544;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px #FFE544;
}
.test2 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px #EEC300 outset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px #FFDD44;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px #FFDD44;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px #FFDD44;
}
.test3 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px #EEB600 outset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px #FFD444;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px #FFD444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px #FFD444;
}
.test4 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px #EA0 outset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 3px #FFCC44;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 3px #FFCC44;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 3px #FFCC44;
}
.test5 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px #EEB600 outset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px #FFD444;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px #FFD444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px #FFD444;
}
.test6 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px #EEC300 outset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px #FFDD44;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px #FFDD44;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px #FFDD44;
}
.test7 {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px #EED000 outset;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 1px #FFE544;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #FFE544;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 1px #FFE544;
}
```

Comment: See @positLabs answer for an IE10+ answer, just wanted to comment on your use of classes: you could've factorized by having a (lasting) class like `.test { /* padding, width, border */ }` and a dynamic one `.testN { border-color, (-prefix-)box-shadow */ }` so you can modify former values in one place (and also save a few bytes of download but it'd gzip well nonetheless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty easy with css transitions (but only for new versions of browser)

[Here is demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMISingh/E7872/)

Just add a transition property to your css class and in that define on which property you want to put transition on (in your case border shadow) and also define for how much time you want to make the transition.

```
    transition: box-shadow 1s;
```

Answer (score 3):

Wow! You're dedicated! There are much easier ways to animate with css. Check out CSS transitions (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)